# I have dynamic value in Request body but it does not available in the any previous request of response.how to correlate using jmeter

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

For example.

I having the dyanmic value = 12as

But this value is not available in the any kind of response.

And that dynamic value *12as* shows same request of response header.

Even i tried to correlate it using response header option in jmeter.

But how to replace it in the same request...?

So i dont know to find the correlation way. Could you please tell me how to do that in jmeter that would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

If it's not present in any of the previous responses it might be the case it's being **generated** in the browser using some form of a [JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

So try locating the relevant function and implementing the same logic in the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

It might also be the case that the value is just hard-coded so you can leave it intact or declare in [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) in case it will change in future.